# Unable to start openssh server windows 7

Tags: git, shell, cmd, cygwin, openssh

I get

```
The OpenSSH Server service could not be started.
The service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534
```

When I try and run `net start opensshd`.

There is no OpenShh log file in var/log for some reason.

I have command prompt opened as administrator and I have set up the passwd file.
Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: did you start it as administrator?

Comment: yes I did start it as administrator.